# Bitnami Mean Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, bitnami

I have installed mean stack manager, but when I run command using node terminal `console.log("Hello World")` it works fine, but whenever I put Javascript sample file to any folder or anywhere in the mean stack install directory or install modules every it don't console the file, so I need your suggestions to where I have to put the Javascript file in mean stack manager to console the file.

> Bitnami MEAN STACK MANAGER

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

The easiest way to play with node is using its interactive shell. Go to your installdir (in your case `D:\New Programmes\New Server`), double click on use_meanstack and execute:

> $ node

Then, you should see `>` indicating that node is waiting for instructions.

You can also write all the instructions in a file with `js` extension (sample.js) execute it directly using:

> $ node sample.js

You can place this file anywhere you want. By default, Meant Stack working directory is installdir, so you can place you file into `D:\New Programmes\New Server` to test it directly writing `$ node sample.js`. However, I think it would be a good pratice to place it under `nodejs` folder (in your case `D:\New Programmes\New Server\nodejs`). If you put sample.js there, you should execute

> $ node nodejs\sample.js

I hope it helps